# Starting memcached: Item max size cannot be less than 1024 bytes

Tags: php, apache, centos, memcached

I have a godaddy vps server. For some reason i restarted it. But after restarting i need to start memcached server which is session handler for PHP. But when i am trying to start memcached using command `service start memcached`, it is showing following error
Starting memcached: Item max size cannot be less than 1024 bytes.
Can anybody help me out what is this error about.
My server is running on centOS 6.6

Comment: Can you confirm whether this is a fatal error which prevents memcache from starting or simply a warning?

Comment: How do i know that this is a fatal error or warning. Please tell me.

Comment: This is a fatal error, memcached is failed from starting.

Comment: The reason I ask is there is a lot of results on google that these are startup tests that are failing. Failing but continue on. @Vinit Chouhan Can you please run the start command then after it has 'failed' try the command "service memcached status" and provide us the output.

Comment: You could also edit your post with the contents of /etc/sysconfig/memcached (or whereever your memcached config is)